# Passing selected row contents to a custom button in maintenance generator

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I've created my own maintenance generator for a table.

**How could I pass selected row/rows content to a custom button?**

For example, user selects a row and clicks on a custom button at toolbox level - after clicking he/she should get additional information on the selected row in a new screen.

Comment: Explore the example https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/11/how-to-create-custom-button-in-tmg/

Comment: I agree with the example shown by Suncatcher + use this code (not OO-compatible) to loop at the selected rows: `LOOP AT EXTRACT. IF <xmark> = 'X'. ENDIF. ENDLOOP.`

Comment: Thanks, I've sort out how to adjust button and inner logic, the article was pretty helpful.